# Cancel Animation on Click instead of hover - JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm just wondering if there is a way to cancel an animation on click instead of hover. The fiddle below uses hover to stop the effect. I tried something similar like this approach but seems a bit different required here.

What I would like if you click the `li` again it will reset like if you're not hovering over the div anymore. And when you click `li` it will start the animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/htmlboy/qQyhE/

**JQuery Code**

```
//animate with no stop()

$(".nostop li").hover(
  function () {
      $(this).animate({width:"100px"},500);
  },
   function () {
    $(this).animate({width:"80px"},500);
  } 
);

//animate with stop()
$(".stop li").hover(
  function () {
      $(this).stop().animate({width:"100px"},500);
  },
   function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({width:"80px"},500);
  } 
);
```

Comment: Use `.click()` instead of `.hover()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check if the element is being animated and trigger `.stop()` or `.animate()` again:

```
$(".stop li").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':animated')) {
    $(this).stop();
  } else {
    $(this).animate({
      width: "100px"
    }, 1000);
    $(this).animate({
      width: "80px"
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qQyhE/47/)

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below solution:

```
//animate with no stop()
$(".nostop li").on("click",function(){
 if( $(this).width() == "100")
    $(this).animate({width:"80px"},500);
    else
     $(this).animate({width:"100px"},500);
  }
);

//animate with stop()
$(".stop li").on("click",function(){
 if( $(this).width() == "100")
    $(this).stop().animate({width:"80px"},500);
    else
    $(this).stop().animate({width:"100px"},500); 
  }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qQyhE/45/